# TPU training freezes in the middle of training

Tags: neural-network, cloud, google-compute-engine, tpu

I'm trying to train a CNN regression net in TF 1.12, using TPU v3-8 1.12 instance. The model succesfully compiles with XLA, starting the training process, but some where after the half iterations of the 1t epoch freezes, and doing nothing. I cannot find the root of the problem.

```
def read_tfrecord(example):
    features = {
        'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'labels': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
    sample=tf.parse_single_example(example, features)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(sample['image'], channels=3)
    image = tf.reshape(image, tf.stack([540, 540, 3]))
    image = augmentation(image)
    labels = tf.decode_raw(sample['labels'], tf.float64)
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, tf.stack([2,2,45]))
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    return image, labels

def load_dataset(filenames):
    files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filenames)
    dataset = files.apply(tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset, cycle_length=4))
    dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.map_and_batch(map_func=read_tfrecord, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True))
    dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(1024, -1))
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=1024)
    return dataset

def augmentation(img):
    image = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)/255.0
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=25/255)
    image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
    return image

def get_batched_dataset(filenames):
    dataset = load_dataset(filenames)
    return dataset


def get_training_dataset():
    return get_batched_dataset(training_filenames)

def get_validation_dataset():
    return get_batched_dataset(validation_filenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is an issue in the data pre-processing function, take a look at the troubleshooting documentation [Errors in the middle of training](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#errors_in_the_middle_of_training), it could be helpful to get a guidance.

I did not catch anything strange with your code.

Are you using [Cloud Storage Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/storage-buckets) to work with those images and files? If yes, Are those buckets in the same region?

You might use [Cloud TPU Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/audit-logs) to determine if the issue is related with the resources in the system or how you are accessing your data.

Finally I suggest you to take a look in the [Training Mask RCNN on Cloud TPU](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/mask-rcnn)
documentation.